# .bashrc iTerm2 PS1

Tags: macos, terminal, iterm2

I've just installed iTerm2 on my computer and oh-my-zsh. Everything is working fine except that it's displaying "➜  ~ git:(master) ✗" as my PS1. I'm not sure what this token is called. Anybody?

I'm trying to change it to something shorter and to remove my git branch information. It shows it for every dir.

I've checked both ~/.bashrc and ~/.bash_profile

Any help would be great. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Both `.bashrc` and `.bash_profile` are to be used by `bash`, not `zsh`. Check `zsh` manpage for details on startup scripts.

Comment: Thanks I'm markig this as the right answer as it really did push me in the right direction. I needed to edit it in ~/.oh-my-zsh/oh-my-zsh.rc

Answer (score 0):

Oh-my-zsh uses its own themes. You **should not edit its startup file** in the `~/.oh-my-zsh` folder, as this one will be changed anytime you update oh-my-zsh and you would lose your customizations.

Check your `~/.zshrc` startup file, which Zsh created for you and oh-my-zsh should have modified on its first execution.

There, you'll find something like:

```
# Set name of the theme to load.
ZSH_THEME=...
```

Replace the `ZSH_THEME` with any of those [you can find here](https://github.com/robbyrussell/oh-my-zsh/wiki/themes). Some themes don't display Git information at all.

If what you merely want to change is the prompt (i.e. the thing that's shown before your input), setting `PS1` manually in your `.zshrc` will do – many [options for that exist as well](http://stevelosh.com/blog/2010/02/my-extravagant-zsh-prompt/).